# Is human cloning permitted in the 31st century?

Tags: futurama

Cubert Farnsworth (Professor Farnsworth's clone) appears in the episode "A Clone of My Own". I was wondering if human cloning is permitted in the 31st century? Or is Professor Farnsworth making Cubert illegally?

Answer (score 9):

It would appear to be permitted, since other clones have appeared on the show, *specifically* in high-profile political positions that you would assume they couldn't hold if they were an *illegal* clone:

- [John Jackson](http://theinfosphere.org/John_Jackson), the [Fingerlican](http://theinfosphere.org/Fingerlicans) candidate in the [3000 election](http://theinfosphere.org/Earth_presidential_election,_3000) and the clone of...
- ...[Jack Johnson](http://theinfosphere.org/Jack_Johnson), the [Tastycrat](http://theinfosphere.org/Tastycrat) candidate in the [3000 election](http://theinfosphere.org/Earth_presidential_election,_3000).
- [The headless clone of Agnew](http://theinfosphere.org/Headless_clone_of_Agnew), [Nixon](http://theinfosphere.org/Richard_Nixon%27s_head)'s vice president and the clone of the [headless body of Agnew](http://theinfosphere.org/Headless_body_of_Agnew).

Comment: They also have a law about clones.  Double Jeopardy!